# How can I know the unit of the shell size command?

Tags: ubuntu, filesize

What is text unit of the `size` linux command?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/iot_c3 $ size t128
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
19102       324       8   19434    4bea t128
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The units for the output of the GNU size command are in bytes. The [`text`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) segment (or code segment) outputs the size of the program that contains executable instructions.

Also the sum of the `text`, `data`, and `bss` sections equals the `dec` field.